# GDB breaks at the end of function instead of specified breakpoint

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, gdb, breakpoints

Well this is odd, I was trying to debug one of my program using gdb.

Here is the relevant piece of the code

```
   137
   138  void solve() {
   139      string input1, input2;
   140      cin >> input1;
   141      cin >> input2;
   142      reverse(input1.begin(), input1.end());
   143      reverse(input2.begin(), input2.end());
   144      ll i1 = atoi(input1.c_str());
   145      ll i2 = atoi(input2.c_str());
   146      cout << i1<<" "<<i2;
   147      ll out = i1+i2;
   148      while(out%10 == 0) {
   149          out = out%10;
   150          cout << out;
   151          cout <<"per: "<< out%10<<endl;
   152      }
   153      cout << "Sum: "<<out;
   154      string output = to_string(out);
   155      reverse(output.begin(), output.end());
   156      cout << endl;
   157      cout << output << '\n';
   158  }
   159
   160  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   161      //string s = (argc == 1) ? argv[0] : "file.test";
   162      //freopen(s.substr(s.find("/") + 1,s.rfind(".")-2).append(".test").c_str(),"r",stdin);
   163      ll t,j;
   164      scanf("%lld",&t);
   165      while(t--) {
   166          solve();
   167      }
   168      return 0;
   169  }
```

I have a script that compiled file using

```
g++ -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -static -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -Isrc -rdynamic -fomit-frame-pointer -o addrev.out addrev.cpp
```

So what I did was that, I set a breakpoint at line 149. But when I run it, it breaks at 158, which I never mentioned.

Here is the gdb's output:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 chaudhary chaudhary 5.4K Nov 15 23:17 addrev.cpp
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 chaudhary chaudhary  87K Nov 15 23:17 addrev.out*
chaudhary@localhost:~/code/codpro/spoj$ gdb addrev.out 
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.7.1-21.fc20
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from addrev.out...done.
(gdb) b 149
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40186c: file addrev.cpp, line 149.
(gdb) l 149
144         ll i1 = atoi(input1.c_str());
145         ll i2 = atoi(input2.c_str());
146         cout << i1<<" "<<i2;
147         ll out = i1+i2;
148         while(out%10 == 0) {
149             out = out%10;
150             cout << out;
151             cout <<"per: "<< out%10<<endl;
152         }
153         cout << "Sum: "<<out;
(gdb) r < addrev.test 
Starting program: /home/chaudhary/code/codpro/spoj/addrev.out < addrev.test
42 1Sum: 43
34

Breakpoint 1, solve () at addrev.cpp:158
158     }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
8534 457Sum: 8991
1998

Breakpoint 1, solve () at addrev.cpp:158
158     }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
503 4970per: 0
0per: 0
0per: 0
0per: 0
0per: 0
0per: 0
.
.
.
Infinite loop
```

Is there some specific reason why it breaks at the end of function instead of the breakpoint.

Comment: You shouldn't debug with optimisations on. Use `-O0` or `-Og`

Comment: I would get rid of most optimisation flags on the compiler command line when targeting debug.You should drop the  `-fomit-frame-pointer` too.

Answer (score 1):

The GDB debugger usually breaks at the nearest assembly language instruction.

There are some times, due to optimizations, that the source code listing does not match the assembly language listing.

Try printing a listing that has assembly language interleaved with source code.  You'll see where it breaks.

Also, where the breakpoint is set is a policy of the debugger.  Some debuggers like to set breakpoints on the first line of a multiline statement; others like to place it at the end.

Inline code will also "adjust" where the execution stops when a breakpoint is trigger and where you can set the breakpoint.

For the best correlation between source code and debugger, turn off all optimizations.  Get your code working correctly first without optimizations, then crank up the optimizations, *as necessary*.